Kube-Prometheus-Stack doesn't scrape some Ingress Nginx metrics
I've been using both Kube-Prometheus-Stack and Ingress-Nginx helm charts. I tried following this guide in the official docs and it did help getting the Ingress target and some of its metrics like in the picture below but it's missing some the metrics that are specified in the Ingress docs like nginx_ingress_controller_requests which I'm trying to use in order to monitor Nginx's status codes metrics. Everything is configured as said in the guide i mentioned earlier. Below are the currently available metrics. Does anyone know what's missing?


I found the solution. According to this github issue, all that's needed is to add the following arg to the Ingress Nginx deployment: --metrics-per-host=false
